# Adventureworks sqlzoo

Tags: sql

A "Single Item Order" is a customer order where only one item is ordered. Show the SalesOrderID and the UnitPrice for every Single Item Order

Hi, 
I tried this question and this is my answer below:

```
SELECT s.salesOrderID, s.UnitPrice
FROM SalesOrderDetail s
INNER JOIN Product p ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY s.salesOrderID, s.unitPrice
HAVING count(s.OrderQty) = 1
```

.please let me know if this is current or else provide a solution .Looking for answers

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
SELECT MAX(s.salesOrderID) as salesOrderId, MAX(s.UnitPrice) as UnitPrice
FROM SalesOrderDetail s
GROUP BY s.OrderID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Based on your query, `UnitPrice` is in `SalesOrderDetail` not `Product`, so the `JOIN` is not necessary.  If `UnitPrice` is really in `Product`, then you need the `JOIN`.

Note the logic of the query.  You want to count the number order detail records *per order*.  So, that should be the aggregation.  The `HAVING` clause ensures that there is just one detail record for the order.

Hence, the `MAX()` function return the values on that single row.

Answer (score 0):

I took the question to mean a customer order of *exactly* one type of item with a order quantity of 1. The JOIN is unecessary as all the needed data is in one table. Here was my solution:

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, UnitPrice
FROM SalesOrderDetail
WHERE SalesOrderID IN
(SELECT SalesOrderID
    FROM SalesOrderDetail
GROUP BY SalesOrderID HAVING COUNT(ProductID) = 1) AND OrderQty = 1
```

This eliminates orders that have more than one item of a single quantity.

SQLZoo doesn't have smiley faces for these answers, so I'm not sure if I'm correct ;)